# App specific user information with Identity Server 4/Indentity

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm new to Identity Server and OAuth in general.  I was wondering the best way to handle App Specific User Info in my Application user table.  I currently have my Identity Server w/ Identity setup and am able to register and login.  I want to separate this into a separate database and have another user table for my first application that is used as the relation between app relationships to a user.

My question is if I follow a process of when a user registers or logs in for the first time, I have a column in my app user table to store the sub as a reference (not foreign key since separate db) to "register" with the app a relation between my Identity user and app user which the app user table stores the app specific info and the sub id.  Will this be an ok way of handling the relationship between identity server/Identity user and my application and will this work if I want to add in say Google login as well?  If not what is a better way of handling the process of a relation between app user info and Identity?